# What happens when our muscle tense?

Tags: physiology, homework, terminology, muscles

Is the tensing of muscles equivalent to stretching them? I am trying to understand what tensing of the muscles means.

Comment: Do you mean to ask the sarcomeric state of the muscle while maintaining posture?

Comment: Stretching of muscle means muscle getting relaxed while "if you tense your muscles, or you or your muscles tense, they become tight and stiff, especially because you are not relaxed" (http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tense_3). So, tensing can be called a consequence of stretching of muscle.

Comment: The course-work tag is nonexistent.  Please don't put it back.  Edits made by hi-rep users are often made for a reason.

Comment: @WYSIWYG *et al*; what is not clear in this question?

Comment: @Christiaan *"Is the tensing of muscles equivalent to stretching them"* What kind of equivalence is the OP referring to is unclear. *Tensing* is a standard English term and nothing specifically biological.

Comment: @WYSIWYG true, it's all about terminology. OP is likely trying to grasp what a regular word means in terms of the biological mechanism behind it. At least, that's what I understand and that's what I've answered. I don't think it should be closed. If it needs closure than the *unclear what you are asking* seems invalid to me.

Comment: @Christiaan That's the point. This question can have multiple interpretations. 1. what you said 2. whether tensing/extending involve same molecular mechanisms 3. whether they are mechanically equivalent... and many more so. That's why I VTCed this as unclear. Plus OP did not respond to comments requesting clarification, for more than a week. Moreover *"What happens when our muscle tense"* is basically a homework type of question.

Answer (score 2):

Muscles are designed to contract i.e., when they tense they get shorter. Their stretch is a passive process, typically facilitated by antagonist muscles in case of skeletal (striated) muscles. Consider the biceps and triceps antagonists in the upper arm in Fig. 1:

[image: arm]
<sup>Fig. 1. **Left**: The biceps actively contracts to bend the arm and is called the agonist. The triceps is inactive and is passively stretched by the biceps, called the antagonist. **Right**: To stretch the arm, the reverse happens, i.e. the triceps contracts and is now called the agonist. The biceps is now inactive and is called the antagonist and it is passively stretched by the triceps. Source: [Pilates Studio](https://plankpilates.wordpress.com/tag/antagonist-muscle/)</sup>

At the molecular level, the tensing of muscles can be readily seen as contraction, as opposed to stretching (Fig. 2):

[image: molecular muscle]
<sup>Fig. 2. Muscle fibers contract actively and stretch passively. The passive stretched state is depicted in the upper panel. Under the influence of ATP (active part) the muscle fibers condense and the muscles contracts. source: [Emaze Presentations](https://www.emaze.com/@AIWCLCFI/Topic-13-and-6.4).</sup>

<sub>**Further Reading**

**-** [Do both ends of a muscle contract?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29655/do-both-ends-of-a-muscle-contract?rq=1)</sub>